# “Operation cancelled” popup on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

The following screen has popped up without any user interaction. Already twice in the afternoon.

I have been wrongly receiving SMSs from an Apple service provider telling me the part I ordered has been delivered. I've contacted the company to see if it might be them. I also use salt as a cellular carrier.

[image: ios error message on screen]

How can I trace or stop this?

Comment: Same here, I am from Switzerland as well. Maybe it is a local Salt (my provider) thing...

Comment: Great to know someone else has the same issue. There’s a high chance that Salt is the problem then.

Comment: I just got the same thing and I‘m also a Salt customer. I‘m confused as hell...

Answer (score 2):

this clearly comes from your provider.

Most probably it is a new network profile which could not be downloaded. 
simply restart the iPhone once. So it dials into the network again and the problem should be solved.